# DKIM result: wrong body hash with single mail address

Tags: exchange-server, dkim

so we got Exchange Servers and Sophos UTM, that signs our mails. We recently discovered, that there is a single mail address, that fails dkim. As soon, as you change the users mail address, dkim works as it should. Even if you give this mail address to a completely different user, dkim still fails. There are no non standard characters in the mail address either.

I'd appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Notice the display name.
Exchange uses it by adding it to an email address.

If a dot is present in the display name, then Exchange will behave non-rfc and will not enclose the string in quotation marks.
Next, the dkim daemon will sign the message, and mta, which performs the final forwarding, will add quotes, which will cause dkim checks to fail later.

- example <email@example.com> - RFC compliant
- example.com <email@example.com> - not RFC compliant (exactly what Exchange does)
- "example.com" <email@example.com> - RFC compliant

In my case, the mail stream looked like this:
MS Exchange > OpenDKIM > sendmail

After being signed by the OpenDkim daemon, sendmail converted the address to the format corresponding to rfc, which in fact led to a change in the already signed letter.